Properly disabling AWS S3 Golang service log
I'm having trouble figuring out how to disable logging for the AWS S3 client in Golang. The documentation isn't super clear and quite inconsistent.
Here's my code:
logger := aws.NewConfig().Logger
cfg, err := awsConfig.LoadDefaultConfig(
    context.TODO(),
    awsConfig.WithLogConfigurationWarnings(false),
    awsConfig.WithLogger(logger),
    awsConfig.WithCredentialsProvider(
        credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(
            config.R2Key,
            config.R2Secret,
            "",
        ),
    ),
)

I'm defining a customer logger with the hopes of overriding the output with a noop. I'm trying to define a null logger (since one doesn't exist that I can find) because the library seems to by default output logs such as:
The endpoint provided in config is <...>

I'd like to disable logging entirely. The documentation isn't super clear
